# How to merge duplicate lines into one line separate by comma

Tags: awk, merge

I have the following data:

```
St1 apt1
St1 apt2
St2 apt5
St3 apt6
St3 apt7
St3 apt8
```

I would like to merge the duplicate lines and separate the fields by comma and have 2 columns, for example:

```
St1 apt1,apt2
St2 apt5
St3 apt6,apt7,apt8
```

I tried the command bellow, but did not work as expected:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}; BEGIN{OFS="\t"}; { arr[$1] = arr[$1] $2 }   END {for (i in arr) print i arr[i] }'
```

The result was:

```
St1apt1apt2
St2apt5
St3apt6apt7apt8
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Trivial with [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/): `datamash groupby 1 collapse 2 < data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a couple of tweaks:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS=FS}; 
    { arr[$1] = arr[$1] == ""? $2 : arr[$1] "," $2 }   
    END {for (i in arr) print i, arr[i] }
' data
St1    apt1,apt2
St2    apt5
St3    apt6,apt7,apt8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '
   :a
   $!N
   s/^\(\(\S\+\)\s\+.*\)\n\2\s\+/\1,/;ta
' yourfile
```

---

### Results

```
St1 apt1,apt2
St2 apt5
St3 apt6,apt7,apt8
```